# Datepicker compatible with dayjs

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, dayjs

I'm trying to move from momentjs to dayjs, however my React project is using rc-calendar to display calendar ranges and datepickers. Rc-calendar uses momentjs date formats and does not work with dayjs.

I'm having trouble finding a daterange library which would be compatible with dayjs for internalization (and not use moment or date-fns under the hood) or be library agnostic.

Would appreciate if anyone has any datepicker library suggestions for this case!

Answer (score 1):

I saw that Ant Design version 5 uses dayjd for the data picker.

https://ant.design/components/date-picker